# Two threads accessing same object produce unexpected result

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6

I found a bug in our system today but I am unable to understand why it happens. I am asking for an explanation of how EF6 and C# work here, because I think I am missing something very important.

My question is "What is happening here", not "How to make it working". The fix is quite trivial - I can add some locks to prevent race condition, but I just do not understand how is this possible.

I have ASP.NET web application in C# using EF6. The design is quite simple - we have users and tasks. Users have their balance and if it is non-zero, they can start tasks. Tasks are executed asynchronously and the application receives HTTP POST callback with results once a task is finished. We allow the user to actively ask our system whether or not the task is finished already. If it is not finished, we tell the user that it is not finished, if it is finished, we give him the result.

It may happen that a task fails, in which case we do not want to count it towards user's balance. This is why the balance is modified after we receive the task results via callback and only if the task succeeded.

So, here is a shortened code snipped from the callback handling routine, only relevant lines are displayed:

```
// before this we have extracted taskId and data from the call parameters

// log Callback: Data received
Task task = unitOfWork.TaskRepository.Get(t => t.TaskId == taskId).SingleOrDefault();
if (task != null)
{
    task.Finished = true;
    task.Succeeded = success;
    task.Data = data;

    if (task.Succeeded)
    {
        // log Callback: BillUser
        if (BillUser(task.UserId))
        {
            // log Callback: BillUser succeeded
            task.Paid = true;
        }
        else 
        {
            // log Callback: BillUser failed
            task.Paid = false;
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        // log Callback: Task failed
        task.Paid = true;
    }

    unitOfWork.TaskRepository.Update(task);
    // log Callback: Saving
    unitOfWork.Save();
    // log Callback: Saved

    // log Callback: End
}
```

This is very simple code. BillUser function is a function that runs DB transaction and the function returns true if the user balance was non-zero and if it succeeded to decrease 1 from the balance and save it to DB. If there is any problem or the balance was zero, the function returns false.

We are using unit of work concept with generic repository, so the Get method looks pretty much like the one in here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Similarly Update and Save methods can be found in this article.

The unitOfWork belongs to the controller and is initialized like this:

```
public class TaskController : Controller
{
   private UnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();
```

this controller implements both - the callback handling method, from which is the code above, as well as the second relevant method that handles users requests on whether the task is finished already. That method looks like this:

```
public ActionResult GetResult(string taskId)
{
   // log GetResult: Start
   Task task = unitOfWork.TaskRepository.Get(t => t.TaskId == taskId).SingleOrDefault();

   TaskResponse response = null;
   if (task != null)
   {
      if (task.Finished)
      {
         response = new TaskResponse(task);
         if (response.Succeeded)
         {
            // log GetResult: Task succeeded

            if (task.Paid)
            {
               // log GetResult: Task paid
            }
            else
            {
               // log GetResult: Task unpaid
            }
         }
         else 
         { 
            // log GetResult: Task failed
         }
      }
      else
      {
         // log GetResult: Task not finished
      }
   }
   // log GetResult: End
```

TaskResponse constructor only builds a structure to send to the user from the task's data, it is not an important function here. Important fact is that when a new task is put into DB, it is initialized with Finished set to false and Paid set to false. The only place where we set Finished to true is in the code above.

**Now where is the problem?**

Most of the time the application works, but today, I found this sequence in the log:

```
thread 1: Callback: Data received
thread 1: Callback: BillUser

thread 2: GetResult: Start
thread 1: Callback: BillUser succeeded

thread 1: Callback: Saving
thread 2: GetResult: Task succeeded
thread 2: GetResult: Task unpaid
thread 1: Callback: Saved

thread 1: Callback: End
thread 2: GetResult: End
```

The user's balance was non-zero at any given time. From what I thought about how EF worked, this should not be possible.

Can someone explain what happened? How could thread 2 see task.Finished == true and at the same time task.Paid == false?

Comment: Not sure of your exact problem, but unless you are doing more in your callback routine, why are you saving every single time. As in it feels like you are  saving even when the job is not finished. Do you really to do that. Also it looks like you are always overrride Succeeded before checking to see it the job has already succeeded. Note none of this helps the issue you have, just observation on the code shown.

Comment: When callback routine is called, the task is always finished. It might fail or succeed, but it is always finished. The task.Succeeded is also set correctly there, success variable is filled in the code that is not shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thread 2 interrogated the `Succeeded` and `Paid` properties after the `Save` method started but before it finished. At this point, it is quite possible (indeed likely) that, for a task retrieved from the repository, `Succeeded` might be true and `Paid` would be false.

The callback needs to be transactional, so that as soon as the task finishes, other threads are blocked from accessing to it until it has been updated.

Comment: I don't think Succeeded is relevant. I have a problem with Finished, not Succeeded - at least I think so. My question is about how Finished is true + Paid is false at the same time, not Succeeded. Or am I missing something in your answer? In other words - why second thread did not log "GetResult: Task not finished" ?

Comment: Yes, actually, looking through your code again, I think the only way you can get `Finished` true and `Paid` false is if a) your two task objects reference the same object (try logging out the address, or putting a GUID in the object during `Get` and logging that out from both threads), or b) if something else somewhere sets `Finished` to true.

Comment: The taskId is unique there and yes, both threads DO touch the same task. Do you suggest that EF provided same reference (pointer to computer memory) to both threads so that they really overwrite each other even before Update/Save? In other words, the situation can be solved even without locks just by moving "task.Finished = true" just before Update call? Or in other words again, EF does not give me a new instance of object each time I use Get()?

Comment: The Task ID is of course the same, but yes, what I was getting at was whether it was the exact same object instance in memory. Hence the idea of adding a GUID to the object during the `Get` method to see if that's what was happening. Moving two pieces of code next to each other does nothing to stop something from executing in between. If it really is providing the same object instance, then you'll need to make your code properly threadsafe, using locks or other synchronisation mechanism.

Comment: The problem is that I am unable to reproduce the issue. It happened in production just randomly. It would be good to find a good source of information on how EF works on this level. The assumption is that it provided the same instance, but is it really the case and does it happen always or can one prevent it using some setting?

Comment: The `Get` method - does it use a long-lifetime `DbContext` (or similar) shared among threads? That could well lead to this issue. Ideally you would create a new Context each time `Get` is called (and `Save`, and so on).

Comment: I think so. So if DbContext is shared, it can reuse instances of the same objects, but if DbContext is always new, it will not happen, right?

Comment: Yes, if you create a new context each time, it simply won't have access to objects created by other contexts, so it should avoid the issue.